# Where are the bookmarks in Firefox for Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android

This may be a ridiculously simple question, but where is the bookmarks list in Firefox for Android?

I'm looking at the interface on my Galaxy Tab 10.1, and I can't find the bookmarks anywhere. They're not available when clicking on the top right corner. They aren't available anywhere else.

The only place I can find them is when I open a new tab, I get an interface which shows my bookmarks as one option, along with "History", "All Pages", and "Desktop".

Surely I don't have to open a new tab every time I just want to go to a bookmark?

This is one of those things that's so simple it seems they haven't even bothered to mention it in documentation. At least, not that I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From at least Firefox 11 onwards (may have originated in 10) you just need to tap on the address bar. The dropdown menu with the four tabs you mentioned (including Bookmarks) should appear when you do. This also applies to phones, though the tabs on the phone version appear across the top of the menu right under the address bar rather than along the left side.